# How do you stop posgresql on centos 7?

Tags: centos, postgresql

How does one stop a Postgresql instance, 9.2, on CentOS 7.

I found nothing under `/etc/init.d/` nor a ctl program.

Comment: if you don't enjoy to type postgresql version each time, and if you have just one postgresql instance running, you can `systemctl stop postgresql*`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [systemd](http://linuxaria.com/article/an-introduction-to-systemd-for-centos-7)

Try something like:

```
service postgresql-9.2 stop
```

If that does not work, try to find the correct servicename:

```
systemctl list-units|grep postgresql
```

And retry above command with the part of the result just before the ".service".

Answer (score 8):

On Centos 7 you should use `systemctl`. Ex.:

```
/bin/systemctl stop postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

on CentOS7:

1. definitely 'run systemctl list-units|grep postgresql' 1st and get the full name of the service
2. 'systemctl stop postgresql-??.service'
3. 'su - postgres -c "psql"'
4. and you should get confirmation postgres has in fact stopped:

'psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is
the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?'